How can I disable or remove cups-browsed?
Not using a printer, and I would like to remove the cups-browsed service for better system security. How should I do this?
The package is called cups-browsed and works with some printer features. I tried sudo apt-get remove cups-browsed but that didn't delete all of the cups-browsed data.

The command "apt-get purge" instead of "apt-get remove" will also remove installed configuration files of the package. Also, if you have no printer, you could likely remove the entire CUPS suite of packages.

Do you know how I can quickly remove all these cups packages?
cups-bsd                   cups-ipp-utils
cups-client                cups-pk-helper
cups-common                cups-ppdc
cups-core-drivers          cups-server-common
cups-daemon                
cups-filters```
